# PowerBI custom visual aggregated dataViews values

Tags: powerbi, dataview

Hi,

I'm making a custom visual in a dashboard connected to an Excel spreadsheet.

I just want to fetch distinct values from a column, but my values are always aggregated no matter which dataViewMapping type i use, and i don't want that.

For a column who contains (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3) i get [1, 2, 3] in my dataViews.

I want to get all the values keeping doubles.

For now here is my capabilites.json, simple as hell.

I already tryied other mapping types like categorical and others ...

Am i doing something wrong here ?

```
{
    "dataRoles": [
        {
            "displayName": "Values",
            "name": "values",
            "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure"
        }
    ],
    "dataViewMappings": [
        {
            "table": {
                "rows": {
                    "for": {
                        "in": "values"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I already tryied to modify "column values type" in "Request editor" pannel in PowerBI Desktop to differents values to get this "Don't summarize" option, but that does not affect the data i get.

Does someone knows how to do what i want ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Leothil it not possible to prevent the removal of duplicate rows, It is by design that PowerBI will remove the duplicate rows. Work around will be to add a field to each row with unique value ( eg: Sno ).

There is a similar question answered in PowerBi Comunity. [click here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Table-Visual-Prevent-Automatic-Removal-of-Duplicates/m-p/810265)
Hope fully this helps.